# Is it okay to send a partial html as text/html?

Tags: html, http, mime-types

While I'm sending a HTTP response, is it okay to send a partial HTML as text/html?

e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12

<p>hello</p>
```

It seems incorrect because the content is invalid HTML document.

Comment: OK to whom? Invalid HTML is served as text/html all the time, since a large proportion of the web is made up of pages with at least some invalid markup.

Comment: Besides, since many start and end tags are optional, this fragment is _almost_ error-free HTML!

Comment: @IMSoP OK to every web clients which obey HTTP/1.1 and HTML 4.01 specification. I want that my web site works correctly to every clients which obey the specifications.

Comment: @MrLister I think this fragment is very incomplete because it does not have a head element.

Comment: The head element has optional start and end tags; you can leave those out. Only the contents need to be there. `<DOCTYPE html> <title></title> <p>Hello` is a valid HTML file.